# BigQuery NodeJS: Delete Rows/DML Support

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Is there a way using the NodeJS lib for BigQuery (https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery) to delete rows? Could not find anything in documentation (https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/index.html)

It appears it should be possible using a DELETE statement via DML (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#delete_examples) but I could not find any examples of how to run this example via the NodeJS lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how to execute a `SELECT` query in BigQuery, you do the same to execute a `DELETE` query.

```js
    const query = `SELECT name
      FROM \`bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013\`
      WHERE state = 'TX'
      LIMIT 100`;

    // For all options, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query
    const options = {
      query: query,
      // Location must match that of the dataset(s) referenced in the query.
      location: 'US',
    };

    // Run the query as a job
    const [job] = await bigquery.createQueryJob(options);
```

Just change the `query` in that example for `DELETE FROM ____ WHERE ____`.

Comment: I get this error `UPDATE or DELETE statement over table table1 would affect rows in the streaming buffer, which is not supported`

Comment: I'm excited to announce that mutating DML statements (UPDATE, DELETE, MERGE) over recently streamed data via the BigQuery Storage Write API* is now supported in public preview!! Check it out the feature and how to allowlist your project here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api#use_data_manipulation_language_dml_with_recently_streamed_data.

*This feature only supports recently streamed data via the BigQuery Storage Write API, not the legacy insertAll streaming API.